# Unit Test Failing for Kotlin-Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradlew, kotest

Error :

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface kotlin.time.TimeMark, but class was expected
    at io.kotest.engine.spec.interceptor.SpecFinishedInterceptor.intercept-0E7RQCE(SpecFinishedInterceptor.kt:37)
```

Tried Upgrading Kotlin version from :

```
val kotestVersion = "5.3.0" to val kotestVersion = "5.5.0"
```

but no luck

Also tried upgrading KotlinJvm Version but no success :
Current ->

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
```

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Hello Rahul, it would be hard to help you without a minimal example to replicate this at our end, as the root of problem seems to be vague.

Comment: @U-ways  I saw and followed this post but still it didn't work . https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/2960

Comment: This is most likely a mismatch between kotlin versions because between 1.6 and 1.7 TimeMark went from a class to an interface.